# Can I replace my Shimano RX 100 with a Campagnolo group?

Tags: road-bike, derailleur, compatibility, groupsets

I just purchased a Concorde Mistral with Columbus Gara tubing and would like to transfer my Campagnolo group from an SLX frame that is too big. The Concorde frame has a front derailleur mounting bracket on the seat tube just like the SLX frame I already have. I understand I would be losing the indexed feature the Shimano has, but would it be possible?

Comment: It would help if you could provide more details about exactly which parts you want to swap. In particular the type and number of cogs on the rear wheel is important.

Comment: I'm not 100% so will only enter this as a comment...I suspect if you wanted to change every part of the groupset, you'd be fine. You also need to consider the freewheel body, not normally considered part of the groupset, but which is splined differently between Shim and Campag. Trying to do a partial conversion is a recipe for disaster, these two companies are famously incompatible with each other.

Comment: I would swapping every part including the wheels.  I think PeteH's answer really helped me. I was specifically concerned with the mounting i.e. front derailer and friction shifters on bottom tube for the parts are not on this continent.

Answer (score 1):

As Pete H has commented, a partial swap will probably not work out.

On frames / bikes of this age, things were easier as compatibility was not quite so much of an issue, so some elements could probably work together OK - but if you are not sure / inexperienced, best is to swap everything.

Worth checking, though, that the threads for the bottom bracket on both frames are the same - some Concordes used to be Italian threads, your existing frame may be Enlish and they are not interchangeable.

To check which you have, measure the width of the shell, width-ways (i.e don't try and measure the diameter) excluding the cups that screw into it - 70 mm Italian, 68 mm English.

Comment: +1 for the thread mention. I was thinking the same thing. I wanted to swap out a BB and crankset on an old Gitane once and ran into this exact problem.

Answer (score 0):

With some customization the partial change is possible.

Get a rear sprocket cassette which mounts on Shimano freewheel but is designed for Campagnolo - they are available. So, you can use your old wheels.

Crankset, chain, derailleurs must be changed completely, cross-compatibility with Shimano (with chains in particular) there happens but is neither flawless neither recommended. Be careful with cranksets - your Campagnolo crankset may be incompatible with bottom bracket in the frame, therefore it would need to be replaced.

Levers - it is technically possible to use Shimano ones, but don't. Just for one simple reason - Campagnolo levers are more comfortable and replacing levers is not such a difficult task technically.

Brakes - these will work whatever they are, Shimano or Campa.